# Can we trade Indicators like indices/stocks?

Tags: online-trading

Can we trade indicators/financial indicators , like volatility index, interest rates, GDP, CPI .. as we can trade indices (djia, nasdaq100...etc) ? or it is just indicators for information purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't trade those indicators *directly* since they aren't physical instruments, but you can trade things that give you *exposure* to those indicators.

For example, there are "VIX" ETFs that attempt to track the value of the VIX though derivatives and other instruments. You can also get exposure to volatility of a specific stock or commodity by simply trading options.

For interest rates, you can trade government bonds directly, or funds that hold bonds of various durations depending on what rates you want to track.

CPI can be "traded" through things like inflation-linked bonds (TIPS) that go up and down in value as inflation moves up or down from *expected* values.

Not sure I've ever seen anything that tracks GDP but I can imaging some sort of OTC instrument that goes up and down in value based on GDP.

Comment: "Not sure I've ever seen anything that tracks GDP ..." — GDP-linked bonds.